# A problem occurred configuring project ':google_sign_in_android'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, gradle, google-signin

I try to run **google_sign_in** version **5.4.0** to my pubspec.yaml but I face with error at the start of running my app; besides that in problems, I have 4 line errors with these subjects that are related to **google_ sign_ in** that if I delete google_sign_in from packages, this error remains.

[errors in PROBLEMS in VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnP7H.png)

> The supplied phased action failed with an exception. A problem
> occurred configuring project ':google_sign_in_android'. Could not
> resolve all files for configuration
> ':google_sign_in_android:classpath'. Could not find gradle-7.2.1.jar
> (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1). Searched in the following
> locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2.1/gradle-7.2.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in the Internet situation, and after restarting my laptop and connecting with a valid **VPN** it was solved.